# How to upload video faster to php server

Tags: android, upload, video-processing

I have captured even 3MB video and save it to my android device SD card, I pick it from device and want to transfer it to a php server.  Uploading is working perfectly, but it takes so long, even 3mb video takes 4-5 minute to upload, even I have fast Internet connection as well. So are there any ways to do this uploading task faster? or any other way to do this. Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance,:)

This is my uploading class connectivity and parsing video.

```
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      // conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(1024);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        Toast.makeText(_context,"response code is " +serverResponseCode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                    .getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }else {
        return "Could not upload";
    }
}
```

}
Here is my main activity for background task.

```
private void uploadVideo() {
    class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog uploading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            uploading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading File", "Please wait...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            uploading.dismiss();
            textViewResponse.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Uploaded at <a href='" + s + "'>" + s + "</a></b>"));
            textViewResponse.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Upload u = new Upload();
            String msg = u.uploadVideo(selectedPath,getApplicationContext());

            return msg;
        }
    }


    UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo();
    uv.execute();
}
```

Comment: You need to compress your video file after upload your video into server.

Comment: i also used compression,its takes also more time for compression .

Comment: i can't understand why 3 mb video takes so long .if i use compression then it also takes more time for compression and then also for upload

Comment: Check your upload speed in ookla then paste it here.

Comment: my average uploading speed is 0.40mbps.and downlod speed is 7mbps.tel me?